# How to refresh my website if starts loading in 4 seconds after a period of inactivity

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cron

My starts loading slower if there is no activity for some time. I think that I can prevent this if I make a request to my site in order to break the period of inactivity and keep load times low.

How can I activate a script or a cron job locally, which reloads my website every 5 minutes if there is no activity on the website? I don't have root access to the server. My website is hosted by a provider.

Comment: I almost envy you for having this problem. All of my problems are "there's too much activity" XD

Comment: Please disclose why do you need that? There may be better solution than just loading it.

Answer (score 0):

You can schedule a CRON job with a `curl` command. This will issue a GET request. Note that JavaScript code won't be executed because it won't be handled by any JS engine (just adding this in because of the JS tag).

> */5 * * * * curl -s www.yourpage.com > /dev/null

More info:

[Cron time format](http://www.nncron.ru/help/EN/working/cron-format.htm)

[cURL manual](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: That's awesome, glad to help! Could you mark the answer, please? http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

This cronjob fix the job now my website stays live and fast!

*/5 *   *   *   *   wget -qO- http://yourpage.com/ &> /dev/null

Thank you again for pointing me in the right direction!